# Using MySQL connector in Perfect framework

Tags: mysql, linux, swift, ubuntu, perfect

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL Database using MySQL connector in [Perfect](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect/tree/master/Connectors/MySQL) under ubuntu.

I've successfully created `MySQL.so` file, but not sure what to do next so that I can `import MySQL` and connect to MySQL Database like the code in [MySQLTests.swift](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect/blob/master/Connectors/MySQL/MySQLTests/MySQLTests.swift).

Here is what I've tried

> Copying `MySQL.so` to `Perfect/PerfectServer/PerfectLibraries/` ->
>
> Adding `-I $(PERFECT_ROOT)/PerfectServer/PerfectLibraries` in
>   `makefile` under `/Perfect/Examples/URL Routing` ->
>
> Adding `import MySQL` in `Perfect/Examples/URL Routing/URL
>   Routing/PerfectHandlers.swift` ->
>
> Then I got `error: no such module 'MySQL'` when executing `make`
>   command.

Anyone knows how to use the connectors provided by Perfect?

I'm new to swift, maybe this question is kind of stupid for people who are familiar with swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the `MySQL.so` library from the system libraries path.
I've just done this for the MongoDB connector and haven't testet it for MySQL but I tried to reproduce it for you.

Following these steps should help you out:

> Ensure that you have installed libmysqlclient-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

> `cd` into your MySQL project dir and build it

```
cd /path/to/myPerfectProject/MySQL

make
```

> Make the binaries available to your project:

```
ln -sf `pwd`/MySQL.so /usr/local/lib/
ln -sf `pwd`/MySQL.swiftmodule /usr/local/lib/
ln -sf `pwd`/MySQL.swiftdoc /usr/local/lib/
```

> Ensure your libraries path is availbale to `make`:

```
sudo echo /usr/local/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

> Update the makefile of your project like this: (notice the MySQL linkings)

```
MYSQL_ROOT=/path/to/mysql

SWIFTC_FLAGS = -frontend -c -module-cache-path $(MODULE_CACHE_PATH) -emit-module -I /usr/local/lib -I $(PERFECT_ROOT)/linked/LibEvent \
    -I $(PERFECT_ROOT)/linked/OpenSSL_Linux -I $(PERFECT_ROOT)/linked/ICU -I $(PERFECT_ROOT)/linked/SQLite3 -I $(PERFECT_ROOT)/linked/LinuxBridge -I $(PERFECT_ROOT)/linked/cURL_Linux -I $(MYSQL_ROOT)/linked/libmysqlclient

LFLAGS = $(SHLIB_PATH) -luuid -lswiftCore -lswiftGlibc /usr/local/lib/MySQL.so /usr/local/lib/PerfectLib.so -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker $($(OS)_SHLIB_PATH) -shared
```

> Build your project

```
cd /path/to/myPerfectProject/

make
```